# Apply JsonConverter attribute on Refit request method

Tags: c#, json, .net, system.text.json, refit

I am developing a UWP app using the Refit library to make HTTP requests to an API that returns JSON data.

I have a custom JsonConverter class `NoteDeserializerNet : JsonConverter<List<Note>>`.

I am using that JsonConverter class on another class model in the following way:

```
    public class OverviewResult
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("lessons")]
        public List<Lesson> Lessons { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("notes")]
        [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter(typeof(NoteDeserializerNet))]
        public List<Note> NotesResult { get; set; }
    }
```

In that case I am using that JsonConverter on a property that corresponds to the "notes" object on the API's json response.

---

I have another API endpoint that returns directly that same notes list but as the *root* object of the json response.

This is the method to get data from an API using the .NET Refit library:

```
[Get("/students/{userId}/notes/all")]
Task<List<Note>> GetAllNotes(string userId);
```

I tried to apply the JsonConverter on the method like this, but it is not supported:

```
[Get("/students/{userId}/notes/all")]
[System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter(typeof(NoteDeserializerNet))]
Task<List<Note>> GetAllNotes(string userId);
```

I know I can use the RefitSettings class to set for every request what JsonConverter to use, but I need a flexible and simple solution like the first example. Possibly using an attribute.

---

I tried also to make a class that is a subset of the `List<Note>` type:

```
[System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter(typeof(NoteDeserializerNet))]
public class NotesResult : List<Note>
{}
```

But still it doesn't work for both cases as I would have to return a `NotesResult` object instead of an universal `List<Note>` object from my custom `NoteDeserializerNet` class.

I tried also to find a way to set the property inside of a class as the "root" json path, so that I can use the `JsonConverter` attribute, but apparently there isn't a simple and straightforward way to do this.

```
public class NotesResult
{
    //how can I set that property to be seen by the deserializer as the "root" json path?
    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter(typeof(NoteDeserializerNet))]
    public List<Note> Notes { get; set; }
}
```

How can I apply the JsonConverter directly on one Refit method API call in a simple way, with minimal code?

Comment: Rather than subclassing `List<Note>` you could create a custom `IEnumerable<Note>` [decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) that wraps your `List<Note>` and apply `NoteDeserializerNet` to that.  See a demo console app here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/VS2a5u.  Does that do what you want?

Comment: Alternatively, why don't you want to add your `NoteDeserializerNet` to `JsonSerializerOptions` when constructing your [`SystemTextJsonContentSerializer`](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit/blob/main/Refit/SystemTextJsonContentSerializer.cs#L40)?  Is there ever a situation where you are returning a `List<Note>` and you don't want to use `NoteDeserializerNet`?  Also, can you share a little bit what `NoteDeserializerNet` does?  It's slightly unusual to have a converter for a `List<T>` (rather than for the item type `T`).